# Select Query using (like & in)

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I want to write a Select Query in that I should use both (in & like) under where condition .Is that possible ?

Comment: YES. It is possible. Some sample data and expected results would be helpful. Please add to your post. A `Where` clause could have multiple conditions so it could be done for example: show me all records from table a `where a.id IN (some set) and a.col2 like '%cat'`

Comment: select * from Table where NAME in ( '%Shipping%','%Site%') 
I need to use like in this statement

Comment: Try it and see. If it doesn't work how you expect, ask for help.

Comment: I want to Find Multiple rows  with the help Like keyword

Answer (score 0):

i had your same problem , until i searched and found this syntax :

```
SELECT <columnName> FROM <yourTable> WHERE CONTAINS (<columnName>, '<yourSubstring>');
```

Comment: I need to use multiple records under where statement using like